# How can I show a file in session Storage?

Tags: reactjs, web, session, session-storage

`I am showing form information using Session Storage.When I wanted to upload a file, I couldn't show it in the session.It would be enough for me to send the file name, but I couldn't.`

**Line 500:16:** 'cvbelge' is not defined no-undef    I get an error like 'cvdocument' is not defined no-undef

```
       const cvbelge =sessionStorage.getItem('cvbelge');
    setBilgi(prevState => ({
              ...prevState,
             
  
              cvbelge,
          
            }));


<div class="col-md-4" id="form_cv" name="form_cv">
        <label for="formFile" class="form-label">CV: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile"
        
        value={cvbelge}
        
     
        name="form_cvFile" />
    </div>
```